# Why does my IndexedDB onsuccess response take so much time?

Tags: javascript, angular, indexeddb

Indexeddb onsuccess function takes time to execute the lines of code inside it

```js
  getAllProjects(callback) {
    let self = this;
    this.initDatabase(function (db) {
      let projects: ProjectdtoService[] = [];
      var tx = db.transaction(self.PROJECTS, self.READ_ONLY);
      var store = tx.objectStore(self.PROJECTS);
      var request = store.openCursor();
      request.onsuccess = function (event) {
        console.log("response")
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
          projects.push(cursor.value.projectObject);
          cursor.continue();
        } else {
          callback(projects);
        }
      };
    })
  }
```

The console log "response" is displayed after a delay of few seconds
As I add more data to the db, and try to retrieve the same from indexeddb onsuccess function, it takes time.

Is there any limitation of indexeddb due which this issue is happening?
any link or documentation for this specific issue?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: IE is old and slow and a security threat to use ... anyway, how does the delay compare to real browsers?

Comment: what delays have you MEASURED in IE and other browsers?

Comment: Which version of the IE browser you are using for this test? Are you working with large amount of data?

Comment: I am using version 11 of IE browser and the data stored is more.

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, I found there is delay in other browsers too. Accordingly I have edited my Question. As I add new data to the db, and try to retrieve the data from indexeddb, it takes time depending on the amount of data added. I tried to get any link specific to this issue of mine but was not successful in getting the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if there's a delay in adding to the database, then the question is answered ... the delay comes from the database, nothing you can do from the client

Comment: HI @JaromandaX The delay is in retrieving the data from indexeddb